# Trying to get <img> tag to auto-scale with page size

Tags: html, css

```
<center>
    <img style="width: 100%; max-height: 100%" src="images/ratios/3to2ratio.JPG" />
        This is a classic 35mm Still Film ratio. 3:2
</center>
```

This code ensures the image scales with the page size changing. However, I would like my images to be their original size and be able to scale as well.

Comment: Besides your question, you should avoid the `center` Tag. It's deprecated in HTML 4.01 and not supported in HTML5. Use CSS instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

do :

```
img{
 width:100%;
 height :auto /* to maintain aspect ratio*/
}
```

Comment: If i add that to the CSS, can I remove it from my <img> tags?

Comment: yup...thats the way to do it mate!! :)

Comment: `height: auto` is not necessary. It's the default value.

Comment: I guess the "width:100%" is forcing it to fill the body 100% which isn't what I wanted. I need it to be the images original size inside the body, then when the page scales down, I'd like the image to scale as well.

Comment: @Casualty : see, when you give `width: 100%;`, it means that the image will take `100%` of its container width....so if you want to limit the dimension, my suggestion would be to wrap it in a `div` or set a `max-width` attrib in css

Comment: @NoobEditor Okay, so in my HTML I have this:
    <div id="wrapper">
    <img id="logo" src="images/footer/lcdmonitorsfooterlogo.jpg">
    </div>
and in my CSS I have this:
.wrapper {
    max-width: 50%;
    height: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

Comment: @NoobEditor I want it to take up 50% of the 100% body.

Comment: @NoobEditor but I also need it to scale.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44892/discussion-between-noobeditor-and-casualty)

Answer (score 0):

```
<center>
    <img style="width:100%;" src="images/ratios/3to2ratio.JPG">
        This is a classic 35mm Still Film ratio. 3:2
</center>
```

Do not make your height 100%

Answer (score 0):

```
img {
width: 100%;
height: auto;}
```

try re-sizing this... :)
[codepen.io](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/lBxAu)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, avoid the `center`-tag. To achieve it's behavior of this in CSS, set `text-align: center` to a parent element of your `img`-element.

Use the following to solve your actual problem:

```
img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```